# Why nested element in CSS grid item is not scrollable?

Tags: css

Consider the following code:

```css
nav{
  background-color: red;
  width: 150vw;
  height: 50px;
}

section{
  overflow: auto;
}

main{
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <section>
      <nav></nav>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

I want to do the `section` element scrollable. If I don't set `display: grid` in the `main` element, the `section` element is scrollable.

Same result, if I set `overflow: auto` for the `div` or `main` elements.

Why is that?

EDIT: Notice that I want to keep the original `nav` size, and make it scrollable (instead of making the whole page scrollable)

Comment: min-width:0 to the div

Comment: @TemaniAfif not really, that makes the `nav` smaller, but I want to keep the size and make it scrollable

Comment: no, it won't make the nav smaller. Can you show you me how the nav is smaller after adding min-width:0 ?